# Error : R cannot be resolved

Tags: android, android-intent

in this code i have problem like **R cannot be resolved to a variable** when i import R then new errors occurs like  **bAdd cannot be resolved or is not a field bSub cannot be resolved or is not a field tvDisplay cannot be resolved or is not a field**
i am also clean project using  project-> clean option but error still there 
 package com.thenewboston.com;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int counter ;
    Button add;
    Button sub;
    TextView display;
    @Overridea
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        counter = 0; 
       add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
       sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
       display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
       add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter++;
            display.setText("your total is" + counter );
        }
    });
       sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            counter = --;
            display.setText("your total is" + counter );
        }
    });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

kindly remove these error and guide  me where i am doing mistakes thanks

Comment: This is because you might be importing android.R instead of the R of your package. 
Try writing R. and give a ctrl+space you would find some suggestions among which need to import R related to your package.
It might be even showing an error on the line setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); isnt it?

Comment: counter = --;?? Should be counter--; You probably have an error there too. Also make sure you have no errors in your xml files as they could cause problems too.

Comment: follow what swayam said in the answer. It should help you

Comment: And be sure you are having the R.java file in the gen folder

Comment: Gave +1 to balance the negative vote given by someone. This can be considered as a beginner question in android and should not have been downvoted

Answer (score 1):

Select "**Build Automatically**" so that every time you clean the project, it will be rebuilt. And yeah, make sure you are saving the file before cleaning it (I know it is weird but sometimes the errors refuse to go away until you save it and then Clean it). Make sure that there is **no error** in the files in the **layout folder**, as it sometimes prevents the auto-generation of the code in R.java

Also, make sure that your code in MainActivity.java does not have **`import android.R`**. Eclipse tends to add that when you are managing the imports.

***EDIT :*** Just noticed that there is a syntax error in your code.

```
counter = --;
```

should be replaced by

```
counter --;
```